# How was this fake red mercury video made?

Tags: mercury

I Found on web video make me wondering what the hack is this , how its even possible ,so any one know what is happen can explain to me please

> youtube video B_olJLjgcHc

Comment: There is no red mercury. Some mercury compounds, e.g., HgO and HgS, are red or have red varieties. Cinnabar is a naturally occurring HgS and beautiful crystals exist. Hope this helps.

Comment: Everything about that Youtube video is a cheap fake.

Comment: The video probably shows some other liquid metal (molten, i.e.). Mercury would vaporise before it goes red hot.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because there is no intrinsic or other value in it or to what it refers.

Answer (score 5):

To spare everyone watching the movie (and giving revenue to someone showing fake chemistry), here is a summary:

A container labeled "27/27 | 99%999 | 1/Kg | 001200300 | RED MERCURY | W. GERMANY | WARNING - DANGEROUS | WARNING - OPEN IN LAP" containing a red liquid is first inverted, then a metal wire (safety pin) is placed on it. The metal wire ignites.

Here is the google-translated comment of one of the viewers ("alfa wolf")

> There is a battery inside the yellow metal, if you look carefully there is a gray metal compartment around the mercury, and there are two parts, one of them plus, one minus, when the wire touches the wire, and the wire burns when the high voltage passes. Mercury has no effect.

Here is a screen shot of the relevant bit. You can see that the wire starts glowing where is contacts the metal rim (smallest area of conducting, just like welding):

[image]

Comment: Do not open any shipment of chemical substances that says "open in lap".